# Did this happen to Loki?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Loki was killed by Thanos.

As we know Loki well for coming back from dead. I still wonder he is dead for real this time?

Thor says this to Rocket.

> **Thor**: he may dead or may come back.

And Thanos says this to Loki before killing him.

> **Thanos**: No resurrections this time

Is he really dead this time?

Comment: Loki never came back from dead! he played being dead.

Comment: As of this moment, he is dead. 100%. Will he stay dead? The answer will be pure speculation until 4vengers comes out

Comment: I take his very specific proclamation of declaring himself the Trickster God just prior to this event to mean something other than what we saw happened.

Comment: Can't help the curiosity from the title when it's shown on HNQ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the time,

> Thanos had two of the infinity stones, space and power.  Neither of them give any particular ability to see through illusions.
>  Loki's "trick" was to swear fealty they stab someone in the front; that is not a trick worthy of a god of mischief.
>  Unless Loki was suicidal he had plenty of time to try something to avoid death; on the other hand, Loki's tricks are almost always illusions, and this one looked like his physical body.

We can cheat however:

> Tom Hiddleston had a [6 film contract with Marvel.](http://screencrush.com/marvel-stars-contract-status/) -- Thor, The Avengers, Thor: The Dark World, Thor: Ragnarok and Avengers: Infinity War makes 5.  He is a popular character and they have the rights to the actor for 1 more film.

Comment: Just speculation, but he could appear in Avengers 4 in flashbacks. Like a memory Thor has, "flashback" from Avengers 1, etc. The contract doesn't mean the character has to be living in the film, just that the actor appears in the film in some way.

Comment: "this one looked like his physical body" It could have been some other Asguardian covered with an illusion to look like Loki.

Comment: To add to your point about Loki being a master of deception: he also tried to double-cross Thanos immediately after handing the Tesseract to him. That's insanely idiotic and out of character; he must have had another plan. Even if it was just to feign death and run.

Comment: Disney has announced that Loki and Scarlet Witch will get standalone series on its streaming service, Disney+ so he may be *mostly* dead

Answer (score 15):

There were no tricks this time. Loki tried to fool Thanos, but Thanos did outsmart and kill him. He is dead for real this time unless script writers or producers find a way to resurrect him. This could be done using Time Stone just like Thanos did to bring back Vision. This might happen in the next movie, but till then it's pure speculation.

> **Thor:** He's been dead before, but this time it might actually be true.

We learn throughout the movie that going against Thanos is not something one can survive...

> Even Gamora, who Thanos loved, didn't survive and gets killed during Thanos' hunt for the Infinity Stones.

Comment: Of course, this answer presupposes those that we see die in Infinity war did in fact die, which is kinda the question.  How do you prove Gamora is dead in a world where there is a time stone (see Vision)?

Comment: @NPSF3000 We might see the use of Time Stone in next Avengers movie coming in 2019,  but till then this will be pure speculation. See `unless script writers or producers find a way to resurrect him`.

Comment: @EngineerToast I'm afraid that could be a *big spoiler* unless the next movie isn't following the comic's storyline...

Comment: FWIW, in the comics: Arohyn tbg gur vasvavgl tnhagyrg naq hfrq vg gb haqb rirelguvat Gunabf qvq. Vg jnf n ovt by' erfrg ohggba. (Spoiler hidden via [ROT13](http://rot13.com/).)

Comment: @AndrewT. Good point, thanks. Obscured through ROT13.

Comment: I feel like this answer is only true if you speak in absolutes and take everything exactly as it is fed to you. We have seen Loki come back from what is assumed to be death many times. The only difference now is that somebody said "This time it is for real." But I think it is safe to assume everybody who has "killed" loki has thought that it was real.

Comment: @Marie: We can only go by the evidence of what we see. Obviously we know that some of those that are gone in the movie are expected to be seen in yet to be released movies so can't be dead for good but at this point in time in the MCU we can only report on what we have actually seen in the films. AJ has provided the facts as presented. If people want to interpret them in their own way then that's down to them.

Comment: That was what I was saying though. "There were no tricks this time" and "Thanos did outsmart and kill him" are not facts that were presented. They are statements made by a character who is fallible.

Answer (score 8):

In Loki (the show), we find out the answer to this.

> In Season 1 Episode 1, Loki is watching recordings of events in his **intended** future life, and he stumbles upon his death at the hands of Thanos. Soon after, the recording stops and the words "End of File" appear on the screen.

So to answer your question:

> Yes, he died then and there.

However:

> He deviated from that timeline when he escaped with the Tesseract. So that future probably is not going to happen anymore.

Comment: https://www.forbes.com/sites/paultassi/2021/07/11/has-loki-given-variant-loki-a-way-back-into-the-main-mcu-timeline/?sh=705d7b721d25

Answer (score 1):

In *Loki* S1E5 we get more information.

> "Classic" Loki reveals that he created an illusion of Thanos killing him, and fled into hiding on a remote planet. As soon as he decided to leave, the TVA picked him up. So the original Loki from Infinity War may have done the same, and is currently hiding on that planet.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the new Loki show has came out, it is safe to say that Loki is indeed alive. Since he was taken by the TVA, he changed his death with Thanos. Loki is alive and well with Sylvie.